# Regression for curve fitting

Tags: regression, cross-validation, curve-fitting, splines, interpolation

For a curve generated from dataset points, split the curve into parts and obtain the best-fit degree of polynomial,coeffcients and the interval/range of the split through implementation in python.I am new to ML, can someone suggest me a few concepts to be applied. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Such a technique is called Spline regression: apply piecewise polynomial functions, in python you can use the generalized linear models module in statsmodels. As for how to choose the degrees and where to split I can't think of any method other than cross-validation.

Comment: some links to provide the questioner with additional resources would be useful. It woudl also be a more complete answer if you gave a brief beginners explanation (couple of bulltet points) of spline regressions and cross validation. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for advice